# CSS Styling Issue

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

Ive been following a tutorial reference a drop down menu, and so far i have managed to do the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/rusticblonde/NZVRq/2/

However on the hoverover the submenu seems to have an massive gap on the hover over color. Do i change the ul ul li?

this is the code so far:

```
#cssmenu ul { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#cssmenu li { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#cssmenu a { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#cssmenu ul {list-style: none;}
#cssmenu ul ul {padding: 0;}
#cssmenu a {text-decoration: none;}
#cssmenu {height: 70px; background-color: rgb(35,35,35); box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);}


#cssmenu ul li {
float: left;
margin-left: 15px;
position: relative;
}

#cssmenu ul li a {
color: rgb(160,160,160);
font-family: Verdana, 'Lucida Grande';
font-size: 15px;
line-height: 70px;
padding: 15px 20px;
-webkit-transition: color .15s;
-moz-transition: color .15s;
-o-transition: color .15s;
    transition: color .15s;
}

 #cssmenu ul li a:hover {color: rgb(250,250,250); }


#cssmenu ul li ul {
opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden;
background-color: rgb(250,250,250);
text-align: left;
position: absolute;
top: 55px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -90px;
width: 180px;
-webkit-transition: all .3s .1s;
-moz-transition: all .3s .1s;
-o-transition: all .3s .1s;
    transition: all .3s .1s;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}

#cssmenu ul li:hover > ul {
opacity: 1;
top: 65px;
visibility: visible;
}
#cssmenu ul li > ul:before{
content: '';
display: block;
border-color: transparent transparent rgb(250,250,250) transparent;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 10px;
position: absolute;
top: -20px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -10px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li { position: relative;}
#cssmenu ul ul a{
color: rgb(50,50,50);
font-family: Verdana, 'Lucida Grande';
font-size: 13px;
background-color: rgb(250,250,250);
display: block;
-webkit-transition: background-color .1s;
-moz-transition: background-color .1s;
-o-transition: background-color .1s;
    transition: background-color .1s;
}

#cssmenu ul ul a:hover {background-color: rgb(240,240,240);}


#cssmenu ul ul ul {
visibility: hidden;
opacity: 0;
position: absolute;
top: -16px;
left: 206px;
background-color: rgb(250,250,250);
text-align: left;
-webkit-transition: all .3s;
-moz-transition: all .3s;
-o-transition: all .3s;
    transition: all .3s;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}


#cssmenu ul ul > li:hover > ul { opacity: 1; left: 196px; visibility: visible;}


#cssmenu ul ul a:hover{
background-color: rgb(205,44,36);
color: rgb(240,240,240);
}​
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly you want to remove the red gaps above/bellow the text in the popup right?

You can do this by giving the `<a>` tag inside the popup a smaller `line-height`. At the moment the huge gap comes from the large `line-height` in the rule `#cssmenu ul li a {`

Comment: fab stuff, i will try this. If it works? Will upvote and accept :)